# How to reduce the number of .Net dll running over a network

Tags: .net, networking, dll, ngen

We have a .Net framework 4 software solution with numerous .dll files.

Those files are hosted on a network server, and run from clients on a common remote folder.

We want to reduce the number of .dll files in this server folder.

Some questions do arise:

- Will the bigger merged .dll be slower / faster to start / or to execute than numerous smaller .dll?
- Is there a benefit to use NGen over network library files, in order to optimize it for each client?

Most of those .dll are in fact called from 32 bit unmanaged code, via a COM visible interface.

Comment: This starts off on a bad premise: storing COM servers on a network share is a pretty bad idea.  They need registration, the registry will contain the drive letter that was mapped at that particular time.  Producing hard to diagnose failure when the drive mapping isn't the same later.  Since this needs to be done per machine anyway, you might as well copy the DLLs and get it over with.

Comment: @Hans About COM registration, it is done automatically by the un-managed application at startup, from .reg files retrieved from the server. It works well, using network UNC full path and the HKEY_CURRENT_USER classes path in the registry to register for the current user. A private copy of the .reg stays on the client to register only once, if needed. So we don't have to deploy nor run anything on the client, and still ensure that the proper COM interfaces are used. We don't have problems with COM auto-registration, with this implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single larger DLL shouldn't be any slower to start or execute than multiple smaller DLLs. It could potentially be faster to start, since the operating system wouldn't have to do as much initialization work. I doubt, however, that you'd notice the difference. Having fewer DLLs will reduce the memory footprint of your program by a little bit. Again, not a whole lot.

I would not recommend running NGen on DLLs that are being served over the network. NGen is intended to compile and optimize for the processor on which it's running. If your client machines have different architectures, the NGen image might be less than optimum or it might just fail to work.

**Additions after comments:**

See [Improving Application Startup Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163655.aspx) for more info on improving startup time. Also [Writing High-Performance Managed Applications : A Primer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973858.aspx#highperfmanagedapps_topic10).

Also note that the loader doesn't JIT the entire assembly. It JITs on an as-needed basis. If your program doesn't use a class that's in the assembly, that class's code will never be JITted. Furthermore, a method isn't JITted until first use. So if you never call the method `Foo.Bar()`, then it will never be JITted.

Comment: NGen should be run on Client side, of course. So it will make a private optimized version, according to the Client HW, IMHO.

Comment: But if you run NGen on the client, then you either have to store the resulting DLLs on the client, or in a per-client directory on the network share. That seems to be at odds with your proposed solution of reducing the number of files. It makes distribution of your application much more complex, as you'll have to ensure that the clients run NGen whenever the application changes.

Comment: Are you sure that it won't be slower/faster? Where could I find some info about dll loading, JIT and preparation of library execution on the client side? For instance, if not all small libraries are not used (it does happen, in big SW solutions), won't it be slower to initialize one big library containing some unneeded interfaces?